# Show that the reflection of a disc through the origin is a disc

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

This is a problem from the book "*Basic Mathematics*" by S.Lang (p.225, exercise 13b). It is similar to the one in [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855042/show-that-the-disc-of-radius-r-centered-at-a-is-the-translation-by-a-of-th), with the exception that we're considering a reflection instead of a translation.

Let $D(r, P)$ denote the disc of radius $r$ centered at $P$.

Show that the reflection of $D(r, P)$ through $O$ is a disc.
What is the center of this reflected disc?

**Proof:** Let $R_o$ denote the reflection through $O$. By definition
$$R_o(Q) = -Q$$
for some point $Q$.

Let $X$ be a point on $D(r, P)$. Then
$$d(X, P) \le r$$

For sake of argument, we choose $d(X, P) = s$, for some positive number $s \le r$.

$R_o$ is an isometry, and as such, for two distinct points $A, B$ we have
\begin{align}
d(A, B) & = d(R_o(A),R_o(B)) \\
& = d(-A, -B)
\end{align}

We know
$$R_o(P) = -P$$

Let $D(r, R_o(P))$ denote the disc of radius $r$ centered at $R_o(P)$. We wish to show that for any point $X$ on $D(r, P)$ there exists a unique point on $D(r, R_o(P))$ to which it gets mapped onto, under $R_o$, i.e., that the reflection $R_o$ of $D(r, P)$ is the disc of radius r, center $R_o(P) = -P$.

We have
\begin{align}
d(X, P) & = d(R_o(X), R_o(P)) &&\text{isometry} \\
& = \vert R_o(X) - R_o(P) \vert \\
& = \vert - X - (- P) \vert &&\text{substitution} \\
& = \vert P - X \vert \\
& = d(P, X) \\
& = d(X, P) \\
& = s \\
\end{align}

Whence, the image of $D(r, P)$ under $R_o$ is contained in $D(r, R_o(P))$.

Conversely, let $-X$ be a point on $D(r, R_o(P))$ such that
$$d(-X, R_o(P)) = s \tag{*} \label{*}$$
for some positive number $s \le r$.

We wish to show that every point on $D(r, R_o(P))$ can be expressed as the image of some point on $D(r, P)$, under $R_o$.

We have
\begin{align}
d(-X, R_o(P)) & = d(-X, -P) \\
& = d(R_o(X), R_o(P)) \\
& = d(X, P) \\
& = d(P, X) \\
& = s
\end{align}

Hence, the reflection of $D(r, P)$ through $O$ is the disc $D(r, R_o(P))$, of radius $r$, centered at $R_o(P) = -P$.$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

**Question:** This proof follows the same pattern as [the proof in my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855042/show-that-the-disc-of-radius-r-centered-at-a-is-the-translation-by-a-of-th) and that might explain some of it's ambiguity towards the end while trying to apply the same method I used for translations to reflections.

Is the assumption that $\ref{*}-X$ is contained on $D(r, R_o(P))$ valid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would prove it, if this helps:

We know that $R$ is an isometry, so $d(X, Y) = d(R(X), R(Y))$ for all points $X, Y$. We also know that $R$ is an involution, so $R(R(X)) = X$ for all points $X$. Using both these statements we get $d(R(X), Y) = d(R(R(X)), R(Y)) = d(X, R(Y))$ for all points $X, Y$.

We now have $$R(D(r,P)) = \{R(X) \mid d(X,P) < r\} = \{X \mid d(R(X), P) < r\} = \{X \mid d(X, R(P)) < r\} = D(r, R(P)).$$

In words:

Since a reflection is an isometry (preserves distances), the distance of the reflections of two points is the same as the distance of those two points. A reflection is also an involution, since reflecting a point twice yields the same point. The distance between $X$ and the reflection of $Y$ is, by isometry, the same as the distance between the reflection of $X$ and the reflection of the reflection of $Y$. That latter point is just $Y$ again.

Now the reflection of the disk around $P$ with radius $r$

is the reflection of all points who are closer to $P$ than $r$ 

is all points whose reflection is closer to $P$ than $r$ 

is all points who are closer to the reflection of $P$ than $r$ 

is the disk around the reflection of $P$ with radius $r$.

Comment: Answer appreciated, however, It raises some questions, possibly because I haven't learned set notation yet but... isn't $\{X \vert d(R(X), P) < r\}$ the set of all points $X$ reflected through $O$, whose distance from $P$ is less than $r$? Than you are considering all points of the original disc reflected and their corresponding distance with the original disc center, i.e., not reflecting the center aswell, leaving us with a different set of points that is not the disc.

Comment: The set $\{X\mid d(R(X),P)<r\}$ is the set of all points $X$ in the plane whose reflections lie in the original disc. If you like, I can write out everything in words.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, I would very much appreciate that!

Comment: Okay, it's done.